# Delay reacting to TextChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have WinForms application that reacts to keystrokes in a textbox using the `TextChanged` event. I want to delay reacting until there has been short gap (maybe 300 milliseconds) since the last keystroke.  Below is my current code:

```
private void TimerElapsed(Object obj)
{
    if (textSearchString.Focused) 
    {  //this code throws exception
        populateGrid();
        textTimer.Dispose();
        textTimer = null;
    }
}

private void textSearchString_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textTimer != null)
    {
        textTimer.Dispose();
        textTimer = null;
    }
    textTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerElapsed, null, 1000, 1000);
}
```

My problem is that `textSearchString.Focused` throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

What am I missing?

Comment: A `System.Threading.Timer` runs on a background thread. To access UI elements you must invoke, or use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead. -- Also, it's good practice to _include the actual error message_ in the question. An exception can have any error message, so telling only the exception type will make it much harder to see the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

A `System.Threading.Timer` runs on a background thread, which means that in order to access UI elements you must perform *invocation* or use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead.

I'd recommend the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` solution as that is the easiest. No need to dispose and reinitialize the timer, just initialize it in the form's constructor and use the `Start()` and `Stop()` methods:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer textTimer;

public Form1() //The form constructor.
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    textTimer.Interval = 300;
    textTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(textTimer_Tick);
}

private void textTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textSearchString.Focused) {
        populateGrid();
        textTimer.Stop(); //No disposing required, just stop the timer.
    }
}

private void textSearchString_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Overriding the OnLoad method would avoid the "subscribed to the event correctly" issue, or just use the form's constructor.

Comment: @LarsTech : True... Updated.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
private async void textSearchString_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Delay(300); 
  //more code
}
```